# set text on focus EditText from Button

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, focus, settext

I have a few EditText's and one Button which will put string on EditText. The problem is, that I don't know how to do it to set text on focus EditText. When I'm on first EditText and press btn I want to set text on first EditText, and when focus another EditText and press btn I want text set where I focused. Please help

Comment: I know how to use onClick Listener, and how to put text on EditText, but only to that one static. I need it to work dynamic. Not like first.setText("xx"); but something like focused_editText.setText("xx"); I hope you know what I mean

Comment: Instead of `OnClickListener`, how about `OnFocusChangeListener`?

Comment: ok, thats helpful, but can you tell me how to make it related to btn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of a `OnFocusChangeListener` and a variable to indicate which `EditText` was last focused.

Lets say you have two `EditText`. You would add a `OnFocusChangeListener` to both. When the event fires, you just have to memorize which EditText received focus last. For example like this, using a class variable `EditText lastFocused`:

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus)
        lastFocused = (EditText)v;
}
```

Then, when a user presses your button you simply do:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    lastFocused.setText("Success!");
}
```